# Simply connected manifolds are orientable

Tags: differential-topology

For a simply connected $n$-manifold $M\subseteq\Bbb{R}^k$, I want to show that $M$ is orientable.

Take a point $p\in M$ and take an $n$-disc, $D^n$, around $p$ (we can take it as small as we please). Since $S^{n-1}$ is orientable and $M$ (and consequently $TM$) is simply connected, the orientation map $S^{n-1}\to TM$ can be extended to $D^n\to TM$. So around every point there is such a disc. We can construct an atlas (an orientation) out of these.

Does this suffice to prove the claim?

Comment: Why exactly can the map of the sphere be extended to the whole ball when $n\geq 3$?

Comment: Oh I misread this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space#Formal_definition_and_equivalent_formulations
So these are not true then, are they?

Comment: If you know about covering spaces, I would consider the oriented double cover of a manifold. For connected non-orientable $M$, the oriented double cover $M^*$ is orientable and connected.

Answer (score 21):

Let $M$ be a connected non-orientable manifold of dimension $n$ and let $M^*$ be its oriented double cover which is connected as $M$ is non-orientable. By general covering space theory, there is a short exact sequence $$0\to\pi_1(M^*)\to \pi_1(M)\stackrel{f}{\to}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{g}{\to} 0$$ and so if $\pi_1(M)$ is trivial, then $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \ker g =\operatorname{im}f = 0$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 18):

Here is one way to argue. An orientation of a smooth $n$-manifold is a nowhere vanishing section of $\Lambda^n M$ (i.e., a volume form). This is a real line bundle $L\to M$. Put a Riemannian metric on $M$. This defines a metric on $L$ as well. Constructing a nowhere vanishing section of this bundle is the same as constructing a section of the unit sphere bundle $U\to M$ of $L$ (unit sphere in ${\mathbb R}$ is of course the set $\pm 1$). The unit sphere bundle $U\to M$ is a covering map (since the fiber is zero-dimensional). Since $M$ is simply-connected, the bundle $U\to M$ is trivial. Hence, it admits a section.

Comment: How can one justify that: "Constructing a nowhere vanishing section of this bundle is the same as constructing a section of the unit sphere bundle". Thank you in advance.

Comment: @CarlosCabezas: One implication is clear. For the opposite implication, take a nonvanishing section $\sigma$ and rescale it as  $\sigma/|\sigma|$; the latter is a section of the unit sphere bundle.

Answer (score 13):

I realize that the question is old, but I wanted to present a more elementary approach, which only uses the fact that homotopically trivial loops lift to loops on a covering space.

Suppose $M$ is not orientable. Consider the oriented double cover $p:X \to M$ and pick $x_0 \in X$. Now, let $\lambda$ be a path connecting $x_0$ and the other point in the fiber, call it $x_1$ (here we are using the fact that the double cover of a non-orientable $M$ is connected - since it is a manifold, it is also path-connected). Now, $p \circ \lambda$ is a loop in $M$, which lifts to $\lambda$. Since $M$ is simply connected, $p \circ \lambda$ is homotopically trivial, which is an absurd (since $\lambda$ is not a loop).

Comment: You took $\lambda$ to be an arbitrary path in the fiber. Then why is $p \circ \lambda$ a loop?

Comment: @Error404 $\lambda$ is a path in $X$ which begins in $x_0$ and ends in the other point in the fiber. Thus, $p(\lambda(0))=p(\lambda(1))$, since both $\lambda(0)$ and $\lambda(1)$ are in the same fiber.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo, why $p\circ \lambda$ being homotopically trivial implies $\lambda$ homotopically trivial? In order to prove that, we should be able to find a homotopy for $\lambda$ from a homotopy for $p\circ\lambda$, right? I don't know how to do that

Comment: @rmdmc89 coverings satisfy the homotopy lifting property

Answer (score 7):

I realise this question has been answered twice and is now quite old, but just to correct Daniel's answer:

You don't quite get the short exact sequence you describe, but you get the following;

the oriented double cover $M^*$ can be viewed as a fibration sequence $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}\to M^*\to M$, whose long exact sequence has a piece which looks like $0\to \pi_1M^*\to \pi_1M\to \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}\to \pi_0M^*\to0$.  Now if $M$ is non-orientable, then $M^*$ is connected, and so $\pi_0M^*=0$. If $M$ were also simply connected, then we would have an exact sequence $0\to \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}\to 0$, which cannot happen.

Answer (score 7):

I realize this question is pretty old, but I do not resist writing an argument I feel
is elementary and, at least for me, transmits the idea why it is true.

We may assume $M$ is a connected and simply-connected smooth manifold.
Fix a point $p\in M$ and an orientation $o_p$ on $T_pM$. We will show
how to continuously
``propagate'' $o_p$ along any smooth curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$
with $\gamma(0)=p$.

If the image of $\gamma$ is contained in
a connected coordinate domain $U$ of $M$, this is clear:
let $\varphi:U\to\mathbb R^n$ be a local chart and define $o_t$
to be the orientation of $T_{\gamma(t)}M$ that makes
$(d\varphi_{\gamma(t)})^{-1}\circ d\varphi_p:T_pM\to T_{\gamma(t)}M$ 
orientation-preserving (note that $o_0=o_p$).
In case $\gamma$ is arbitrary, we cover its
image by connected coordinate domains and use the Lebesgue number lemma to
partition $[0,1]$ so that each subinterval $[t_{i-1},t_i]$,
has image under $\gamma$ contained in a connected coordinate domain
$U_i$, where $i=1,\ldots,m$; then we apply the previous case and induction.

We end up with an orientation $o_1$ of $T_qM$,
and we define $o_q$ to be $o_1$, where $q=\gamma(1)$.
Next we show that $o_q$ is independent of the covering
$\mathcal U=\{U_i\}_{i=1}^m$. Let $\mathcal V=\{V_j\}_{j=1}^k$
be another covering of $\gamma([0,1])$ such that $\gamma([t_{j-1},t_j])\subset
V_j$  and $V_j$ is a connected coordinate domain of $M$
for $j=1,\ldots,k$. Denote by $o^{\mathcal U}_t$ and $o^{\mathcal V}_t$ the
orientations of $T_{\gamma(t)}M$ 
obtained by using $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal V$, respectively.
Consider $I=\{\,t\in[0,1]\;|\; o^{\mathcal U}_t=o^{\mathcal V}_t\,\}$.
Of course $I\neq\varnothing$ as $0\in I$. Further, $I$ is open:
if $\bar t\in I$ and $\gamma(\bar t)\in U_i\cap V_j$ then the connected
component of $\gamma^{-1}(U_i\cap V_j)$ containing $\bar t$ is also
contained in $I$. Similarly, one sees that $I$ closed. Hence $I=[0,1]$.

Finally, we show that $o_q=o^\gamma_q$ is
independent of the curve $\gamma$ joining
$p$ to $q$. Given a homotopy $\{\gamma_s\}$ of $\gamma=\gamma_0$
keeping the endpoints fixed and $s_0$, we may find $\epsilon>0$ 
so that $\gamma_s([t_{i-1},t_i])$ is contained
in a connected coordinate domain $U_i$
for all $s\in(s_0-\epsilon,s_0+\epsilon)$ and $i=1,\ldots,m$;
fix $s_1\in(s_0-\epsilon,s_0+\epsilon)$. We proceed by induction
on $i:1,\ldots,m$. 
By construction
$$(d\varphi_{\gamma_{s_0}(t_i)})^{-1}\circ d\varphi_{\gamma_{s_0}(t_{i-1})} 
\quad\mbox{and}\quad
(d\varphi_{\gamma_{s_1}(t_i)})^{-1}\circ d\varphi_{\gamma_{s_1}(t_{i-1})} $$
are orientation-preserving.
By the induction hypothesis on $i$,
$$ d\varphi_{\gamma_{s_1}(t_{i-1})}^{-1}\circ d\varphi_{\gamma_{s_0}(t_{i-1})} $$
is orientation-preserving. Therefore
$$ d\varphi_{\gamma_{s_1}(t_{i})}^{-1}\circ d\varphi_{\gamma_{s_0}(t_{i})} $$
is also orientation-preserving. 
Since $t_m=1$ and $\gamma_{s_0}(1)=q=\gamma_{s_1}(1)$,
  we deduce that $o_q^{\gamma_s}$ is locally constant on $s$; hence it is
  constant on $s$. Since any two curves joining $p$ to $q$ are
  homotopic due to the simple-connectedness of $M$, we are done.