Closed simply connected rationally acyclic manifold
Let $M$ be a closed rationally acyclic manifold of dimension $n$. This means that $M$ is compact without boundary and that $M$ does not have rational cohomology in any positive degree.
Examples of such manifolds include the real projective spaces $\mathbb{R}P^n$ for each $n$ even. In fact, it is easy to see using Euler characteristics that such a closed rationally acyclic manifold cannot exist in odd dimensions, i.e., for such a manifold, we must have $n$ odd.
My question is: if $M$ is a closed, simply connected, acyclic manifold, then is it always true that $M$ is homeomorphic to a point (the trivial $0$-dimensional manifold)? Of course, without the simply connected hypothesis, the answer is no due to the above examples. But what happens in the simply connected case and why?

Yes. A simply connected manifold is orientable, so if $M$ is closed of dimension $n$ then $H_n(M) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, whence $H_n(M; \mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Q}$. But $M$ was assumed rationally acyclic, so we must have $n = 0$ and $M$ is a point.

Thanks Ben. For future reference, here are a couple useful answers why simply connected closed manifolds are orientable: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786483/simply-connected-manifolds-are-orientable
